# Tablefield генерит пустые таблицы после редактирования

Tags: php, drupal

Друпал 7, модуль Tablefield
после редактирования карточки товара - добавляет 1 пустую таблицу( и выдает 2 ошибки

> Notice: Undefined index: hide_headers в функции tablefield_field_widget_form() (строка 607 в файле /home/c/cv55565/timetrial/public_html/sites/all/modules/tablefield/tablefield.module).
>       Notice: Undefined index: hide_headers в функции tablefield_field_widget_form() (строка 642 в файле /home/c/cv55565/timetrial/public_html/sites/all/modules/tablefield/tablefield.module).

```
if (!empty($instance['description'])) {
    $help_text = $instance['description'];
  }
  else {
    if ($field['settings']['hide_headers'] == TRUE) {
      $help_text = t('This table will not have a header.');
    }
    else {
      $help_text = t('The first row will appear as the table header. Leave the first row blank if you do not need a header.');
    }
  }

  $element['tablefield'] = array(
    '#title' => $element['#title'],
    '#description' => filter_xss_admin($help_text),
    '#attributes' => array(
      'id' => $id,
      'class' => array('form-tablefield'),
    ),
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#collapsible' => FALSE,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="' . $ajax_wrapper_id . '">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
  if (!empty($field['settings']['hide_headers'])) {
    $element['tablefield']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'table-no-headers';
  }

  // Give the fieldset the appropriate class if it is required.
  if ($element['#required']) {
    $element['tablefield']['#title'] .= ' <span class="form-required" title="';
    $element['tablefield']['#title'] .= t('This field is required');
    $element['tablefield']['#title'] .= '">*</span>';
  }

  $arg0 = arg(0);
  if ($arg0 == 'admin') {
    $element['tablefield']['#description'] = t('This form defines the table field defaults, but the number of rows/columns and content can be overridden.');
    if (!$field['settings']['hide_headers']) {
      $element['tablefield']['#description'] .=  ' ' . t('The first row will appear as the table header. Leave the first row blank if you do not need a header.');
    }
  }
```

Я так понял - оно вот на это ругается

```
 if (!$field['settings']['hide_headers']) {
```

и именно из-за этого генерит пустые таблицы

Comment: НУ ТАК сделайте вар дамп $field['settings'] и посмотрите что там есть

Answer (score 0):

Все решается - нужно просто было указать в настройка представления кол-во таблиц, а не делать их количество неограниченным. установка максимального кол-ва таблиц 5 - удалила пустые, и новые генерятся, но их кол-во не запредельное (на некоторых страницах доходило до 30 штук пустых)